# QPlainTextEdit subclass function to indent lines in selection

Tags: c++, qt

I am, primarily for learning purposes, working on creating an editor component in C++ with Qt. As a first step, to begin getting familiar with editing a document via `QTextCursor`, I wrote this function on my subclass of `QPlainTextEdit` to indent multiple selected lines:

```
void MyEditor::increaseSelectionIndent()
{
    QTextCursor curs = textCursor();

    // Do nothing if we don't have a selection.

    if(!curs.hasSelection())
        return;

    // Get the first and count of lines to indent.

    int spos = curs.anchor(), epos = curs.position();

    if(spos > epos)
    {
        int hold = spos;
        spos = epos;
        epos = hold;
    }

    curs.setPosition(spos, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
    int sblock = curs.block().blockNumber();

    curs.setPosition(epos, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
    int eblock = curs.block().blockNumber();

    // Do the indent.

    curs.setPosition(spos, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);

    curs.beginEditBlock();

    for(int i = 0; i <= (eblock - sblock); ++i)
    {
        curs.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfBlock, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);

        curs.insertText("\t");

        curs.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextBlock, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
    }

    curs.endEditBlock();

    // Set our cursor's selection to span all of the involved lines.

    curs.setPosition(spos, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
    curs.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfBlock, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);

    while(curs.block().blockNumber() < eblock)
    {
        curs.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextBlock, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
    }

    curs.movePosition(QTextCursor::EndOfBlock, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);

    // Done!

    setTextCursor(curs);
}
```

I'm interested in any feedback on whether or not I'm following "best practices" with `QTextCursor` - am I doing anything weird, or that can be simplified or improved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Some of these comments can be removed:

  Too obvious:

  ```
  // Do nothing if we don't have a selection.
  ```

  Noisy:

  ```
  // Done!
  ```
- These initialized variables:

  ```
  int spos = curs.anchor(), epos = curs.position();
  ```

  should be on separate lines for better maintenance:

  ```
  int spos = curs.anchor();
  int epos = curs.position();
  ```
- No need to do a manual swap:

  ```
  if(spos > epos)
  {
      int hold = spos;
      spos = epos;
      epos = hold;
  }
  ```

  Just use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) to keep it idiomatic:

  ```
  if (spos > epos)
  {
      std::swap(spos, epos);
  }
  ```
- No need calculate the difference each time:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i <= (eblock - sblock); ++i)
  ```

  Define a constant before the loop and use it instead:

  ```
  const int blockDifference = eblock - sblock;

  for (int i = 0; i <= blockDifference; ++i)
  ```